# Cambiar valores null por '0' en un pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, null

Tengo algo más o menos así

```
select * from( selcect ...)as pt
pivot(
asc(valor) for desc in 
(
[Deporte y cultura],[Despensa],[Destajo - sueldo],
 [Destajos], etc ...)
) as pvt
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero obtengo muchos resultados como null de ese **pivot**, alguien podría decirme como cambiarlos por cero?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no te sirve esto? `ISNULL([Deporte y cultura], 0)`

Comment: me da > Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '('. si hago eso

Comment: En vez de usar el `*` usa el nombre de las columnas y haz lo que dije

Comment: lo que pasa es que esas columas vienen del pivot no del select, peor trataré igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `ISNULL` de esta manera:

```
select 
    ISNULL([Deporte y cultura], 0),
    ISNULL([Despensa], 0),
    ISNULL([Destajo - sueldo], 0),
    ISNULL([Destajos], 0) 
from( selcect ...)as pt
pivot(
    asc(valor) for desc in 
    (
        [Deporte y cultura],
        [Despensa],
        [Destajo - sueldo],
        [Destajos],
        etc ...
    )
) as pvt
```

Lo mismo preguntan [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322342/how-to-replace-null-values-with-0-output-in-pivot).

Comment: pues si más o menos funciona, el problema que tengo es que ahora me apareden los datos en null y hasta el final un columna de ceros que corresponde a los isnull, si me explico??

Comment: mi query es muy largo pero editaré la imagen para que veas los cambios y no confundir mucho al lector.

Comment: listo , yo repetía la columna,se puede ver en la imagen , mil gracias