# cambiar valor nulo por 0 en consulta con PIVOT

Tags: sql, jquery, sql-server, jquery-validate, pivot

tengo una situación parecida, uso PIVOT y me regresa algunos valores nulos los cuales requiero cambiar a valores en 0

este es mi codigo

```html
SELECT pvt.*
 FROM
(
    SELECT Fecha, Linea, Dato FROM Dato_Medidor
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Dato) FOR Linea IN ([ELFO_006_Oficinas],
    [ELFO_007_Rim], [ELFO_008_ED], [ELFO_009_FBW],
    [ELFO_010_Disco])
) AS pvt
```

usando la referencia que dan como respuesta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197884/cambiar-valores-null-por-0-en-un-pivot-sql/606163#606163), lo modifique al siguiente:

```html
SELECT ISNULL([ELFO_006_Oficinas], 0),
    ISNULL([ELFO_007_Rim], 0),
    ISNULL([ELFO_008_ED], 0),
    ISNULL([ELFO_009_FBW], 0),
    ISNULL([ELFO_010_Disco], 0)
 FROM
(
    SELECT Fecha, Linea, Dato FROM Dato_Medidor
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Dato) FOR Linea IN ([ELFO_006_Oficinas],
    [ELFO_007_Rim], [ELFO_008_ED], [ELFO_009_FBW],
    [ELFO_010_Disco])
) AS pvt
```

pero con este no me esta separando por fecha

Comment: Según veo, sí está separando por fecha pero no incluiste la columna en la lista.